# Merging Nearby Instances to a single point in Blender Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, particle-nodes

With Geometry Nodes, is there a way to merge all the top 3 points coming from distributed particles into a single point (such as the median point of the yellow sphere) in a scene like pictured?

[image]

Thanks @Chris that was an excellent example. Here I clarified your solution for GeoNode newbies like myself:

[image]

Comment: You do not merge three points with this solution, but all points of the end section of your previously created mesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you mean like this:

[image]

then you can use this node setup:

[image]

[image]